# JAX-RS and Jersey - only one resource of multiple exposed

Tags: web-services, jersey, jax-rs

I've got the start of a RESTful web service using JAX-RS and Jersey that exposes two resources: SessionResource and ItemResource.  Only one of these, unfortunately, is exposed by the web service.

Details:

- configuration is done w/ a class that extends javax.ws.rs.core.Application (created automatically by Netbeans 7).  the class doesn't contain any configuration information other than a @ApplicationPath() annotation.
- no web.xml file

Questions:

- What am I missing?
- is there value to having an application class?  can i get away w/ just a web.xml file for configuration?
- sometimes i've noticed that changes made in the IDE aren't published to apache.  what is the most reliable way to do so?

Answer (score 1):

One of multiple solutions is to override `getClasses()` of your JAX-RS application.

```java
@ApplicationPath("/")
public class MyApplication extends Application
{
    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses()
    {
        return new HashSet<Class<?>>()
        {
            {
                add(ResourceA.class);
                add(ResourceB.class);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

As I learned it is better not to rely on the automatic detection of resources and providers. Sometimes it can have sideeffects if you have more than one JAX-RS application.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in your web.xml and then you shouldn't need the Application class.

```xml
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>JerseyStartup</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>[fully qualified name of a class that extends ServletContainer]</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
    <param-value>com.yourCompany</param-value>
  </init-param>
</servlet>
```

Then it will automatically detect all classes in `com.yourCompany` and its subpackages, which are annotated with `@Path`, and treat them as resources.

Comment: What would the whole web.xml resemble?  I've seen examples w/ servlets, but I haven't been able to find one for Jersey applications (assuming that this is the correct term).

Comment: Can I have a web.xml in addiion to the Application class?  If not, is there another location to set the home document?

Comment: I updated the question. Then you map that servlet to a particular URL pattern. I haven't used an Application class so I don't know about your second question.